# unable to find FASTA index

Tags: linux

I have divided a reference.fasta into subsets using:

```
partition.sh in=reference.fasta out=part%.fasta ways=50
```

Then I build index of these subset files using:

```
samtools faidx *fasta
```

But I use these subset files in freebayes SNP calling it gives error:

```
unable to find FASTA index entry for "gene x"
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Where does `partition.sh` come from?

Comment: Hello, it comes from BBMap